# Why was this question a review audit?

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I got [How does the JVM internally handle race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27192739/1234256) as [a review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6456270) in the First Posts queue. I voted "Too Broad" and got a failed audit message.

I don't think it should have been an audit because it has 3 downvotes.

Comment: That seems odd. I thought keep-open review audits had to be unanimously upvoted and above some score threshold (5 or 10). That question got at least two downvotes the day it was asked.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Three DVs, according to the timeline, and long ago that it's not like the auditing tool could have cached it or something; that's just too long to be going without checking that the question is still appropriate.

Comment: that was a [First Posts](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6456270) audit, known as having [weaker requirements](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168372/165773) than close/reopen ones. But even then, 3 (three!) downvotes smell bad for a "known good" pick

Comment: @gnat: the meta effect is making more than 3, I guess.

Comment: @lpapp I [complained to Shog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168366/failed-a-reopen-question-audit-sure-looks-like-not-a-real-question-to-me/168372#comment802062_168372) when it was at three. Would be _really_ funny if system continue using it as audit at six :)

Comment: Wait, did it have -3 **net**, or -3 downvotes and some number of upvotes?

Comment: @Yakk At the time, it was +16/-3.

Comment: What I find particularly amusing, and perhaps relevant, is that the question was actually "put on hold as too broad".

Comment: @pete That should've happened **before**...

Comment: @Mooseman Seems the Meta-effect has occurred; the question now has 7 downvotes: http://puu.sh/dtpib/82c4d68f35.png

Answer (score 7):

> I don't think it should have been an audit because it has 3 downvotes.

That's not how the audit selection works, except for reviews in the close and reopen queues. Even there, that particular criteria doesn't work terribly well - at some point, we'll probably replace it with [a better one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196949/request-for-review-close-reopen-known-good-audits/196952#196952).

This ended up being a rather interesting audit. It was given to 7 different reviewers; 4 passed, 3 failed. Then, after you posted this question here, it was closed.

...And then it was reopened.

At this point, it's had considerably more vetting than most audit candidates, and has managed to weather it well. I'm curious to know why you think it should have been closed...

Comment: I would *guess* that it is the combination of a compound question (three '?' that are distinct), request for additional insight (final sentence), the lack of a clearly defined problem statement (debatable), and that the internals of the java memory management (that appear to be asked about) fall into the "good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."

Comment: ... this is further expanded on by comments suggesting a bit of misunderstanding of the question (see comments in http://stackoverflow.com/a/27192886/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/27193553/ ).  There's *something* about the question that is problematic.

Comment: @MichaelT Concurrency is hard.  Formal standards are hard.  Formal standards talking about concurrency is harder.  I would expect a question about that kind of question to generate bad answers, as people think they understand it but do not.